# Developing a IAAS for cloud computing

Tags: cloud, iaas

I am looking to create a `IAAS` for my final year project. I have not taken the course of parallel processing until now. Please help me with the problems that I can face and tricks for faster implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to develop Infrastructure as a service you need to have that infrastructure .like if you are using Hyper-V it demands windows server 2008 r2 with minimum 4 gb ram and 50 Gb hard disk.
As you want to develop it for you final year project , i would suggest you to go for Open source .for virtualization technique you can use KVM that comes budled with many flavours of Linux the same can be easily used to create the VMs.
Hyper-v and Vmware are costly choices but for Vmware you can go for 60 day evolution version that can be easily downloadable, in that case you will be required to have a saperate machine to run your Esxi node.
for Hyper-V you can download the DDTK 3.0 from their website and host it on IIS server , you will get a wsdl from it and the same can be used to generate the stubs so that you can call the methods of it and similarly you can build a portal on the top of it .
to get a better understanding you can start with oracle  virtual box...hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

To develop IAAS you don't really need to have that infrastructure, considering you are only testing and no going to "production".

You may simply use VirtualBox or other virtualization software (VS) to run guests from clients.

You can develop a simple server that accepts box images, and once uploaded, then install on the VS, and run it. You must give the client  guidelines on how to prepare
the guests and how to access the guests
when running.

You can do this in two parts: 1st prepare the local scripts on the machine
where the VS is running and later connect the scripts by means of a service
for clients.